# I'm reading in a JSON of nested JavaScript Objects - I want to 'sort' it so objects that have a field with a certain value go to the top

Tags: json, angular, typescript, javascript-objects, key-value

I'm reading in a JSON that has a map of javascript objects. So.. for example :

```
    { 
        offers : {
               "1":{"id":"1", "category":"a", "offerType":"LS"}, 
               "2":{"id":"2", "category":"a", "offerType":"EX"}, 
               "3":{"id":"3", "category":"a", "offerType":"EX"}, 
               "4":{"id":"4", "category":"a", "offerType":"LS"} 

        }
    }
```

When I read this JSON, I am storing it in local storage. I want to "sort" is so that all offers that have offerType of "LS" show up on the TOP of my object in local storage.

The reason I want to do this is so when I display these offers on my site, the ones with offerType "LS" will display first. 
I am doing this is Angular :

```
            let offers = data.offers;
                if (offers != null) {
                    for (var index in offers) {
                        var offer = offers[index];

                        if ( offer != undefined) {
                            if (offer.offerType == 'LS'){ 
                                offersLS = [...offersLS, offer];
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if (offersLS != null){
                        offersLS.forEach(offerLS => {
                           let key =  offerLS['id'];
                           listOffers = offers[key], listOffers;
                        });

                    }
                listOffers = listOffers, offers;
            }
```

listOffers is what ends up getting saved as my local storage object. I have tried to do it like : listOffers = [...offersLS, ...offers] but that obviously saves it in my localStorage as an array and I need it to be a 'map' of these objects or object of objects..not exactly sure what the correct terminology would be.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that sort an object may be a **bad idea**, it's not designed for that. Think about use arrays.

Anyway the solution is quite simple, it's about sort the keys then redo an object based on this new keys order:

```js
const offers = {
    "1":{"id":"1", "category":"a", "offerType":"LS"},
    "2":{"id":"2", "category":"a", "offerType":"EX"},
    "3":{"id":"3", "category":"a", "offerType":"EX"},
    "4":{"id":"4", "category":"a", "offerType":"LS"}
};

let value1;

const sortedOffers = Object.keys(offers)
    .sort((k1, k2) => {

        // your sort rules here

        value1 = offers[k1];

        return value1.offerType === 'LS' ? -1 : 1;
    })
    .reduce((o, k) => {
        o[k] = offers[k];
        return o;
    }, {});
```